# How to make Computed Text be editable in Web Form

Tags: javascript, html, lotus-notes, lotusscript

I have a subform where I write HTML code. My subform just consists of a table and a lot of field information. It will be displayed and also editable. So I am using Computed Text to display the values. What I understand, when using Computed Text, it just displays the text and cannot be editable. But I want that the field can be edited. Below is some example code of my Computed Text.

```
<td width="100"><i>Batch No.</i></td>
<td width="15">:</td>
<td width="340"><Computed Value></td>
<td width="20"></td>
<td width="150"><i>Year</i></td>
<td width="15">:</td>
<td width="150"><b><Computed Value></b></td>
```

Edit Button

```
@Command([EditDocument])
```

Is there any way that I can make the Computed Text editable and then save the content? Because I have edit button to enable edit and save button to save the value.

Answer (score 2):

In the container add 'contenteditable="true"' attribute All right.
hope I can help you.

```html
   <div contenteditable="true"></div>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your suggestion, but when I insert it, all page is editable. I just want the field to be editable. Any way, thanks for your suggestion answer.

Answer (score 0):

No, computed text cannot be editable in a browser. It's computed. You can only change it by changing the formula, or by changing the value of an item that the formula refers to.

Changing the formula can only be done in the Notes client if it is computed text within a rich text field, or in Domino Designer if it is computed text on a form. Changing the value of an item that the formula refers to can be done by putting an editable field on the form or invoking a URL that runs an agent.

Comment: Hi, you mean that if I want my field can be editable then I need to insert my rich text field? Also, what do you mean by changing the formula, or by changing the value of an item that the formula refers to? You mean I need to enable edit using formula in my Domino Designer?

Answer (score 0):

The typical way of handling this sort of situation is to have two fields, one read-only, and one editible and a button that triggers some Javascript to toggle which one displays.  If your data is in a Notes view, a column can be made editable, but that doesn't help when the column's value is a formula.